# Transpose data with MPI_Alltoall and subarrays

Tags: c++, mpi

I need to transpose a matrix distributed across processors using MPI. At the moment, I am using `MPI_Alltoall` to distribute the data, and subarrays to specify the blocks to be sent around. I will then need to implement a similar permutation of the indices for a 3D distributed array.

However, I am not sure whether `MPI_Alltoall` is supposed to work with subarrays.

Here is a minimal working example, in c++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    int comm_rank;
    int comm_size;

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm_size);  // assume 2

    // local array size
    int arr_size[2] = {4, 2};
    int sub_size[2] = {2, 2};
    int   origin[2] = {0, 0};

    // column major data
    int data[8] = {0 + 8*comm_rank, 1 + 8*comm_rank, 2 + 8*comm_rank, 3 + 8*comm_rank,
                   4 + 8*comm_rank, 5 + 8*comm_rank, 6 + 8*comm_rank, 7 + 8*comm_rank};

    // construct subarray types
    MPI_Datatype send_type;
    MPI_Datatype recv_type;
    MPI_Type_create_subarray(2, arr_size, sub_size, origin,       
                            MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, MPI_INT, &send_type);
    MPI_Type_create_subarray(2, arr_size, sub_size, origin,       
                            MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, MPI_INT, &recv_type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&send_type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&recv_type);                             

    // print
    std::cout << "- " << comm_rank << " - \n" 
            << data[0] << " " << data[4] << '\n'
            << data[1] << " " << data[5] << '\n'
            << data[2] << " " << data[6] << '\n'
            << data[3] << " " << data[7] << '\n';

    // transpose data
    MPI_Alltoall(data, 1, send_type, data, 1, send_type, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // print
    std::cout << "- " << comm_rank << " - \n" 
            << data[0] << " " << data[4] << '\n'
            << data[1] << " " << data[5] << '\n'
            << data[2] << " " << data[6] << '\n'
            << data[3] << " " << data[7] << '\n';

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Compiling with `mpic++ mpitest.cpp -o mpitest`, and running with `mpirun -np 2 ./mpitest` results in

```
- 1 -
8 12
9 13
10 14
11 15
- 0 -
0 4
1 5
2 6
3 7
- 0 -
0 4
1 5
2 6
3 7
- 1 -
203412040 2
1 2
10 14
11 15
```

where there is actually no data exchange to rank 0, and some data corruption on rank 1.

My question is whether I can use mpi subarrays with `MPI_Alltoall`, or if I need to handle the underlying data layout myself.

Comment: `MPI_Alltoallv()` will likely work. if the `disps` vector is "regular", then you might be able to use subarrays with `MPI_Alltoall()`, but you might have to `MPI_Type_create_resized()` them first.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet yes, resizing the extent of the subarray does the job. If you make your comment a formal answer I will mark this as solved and edit the question appropriately. Thanks.